# Space in HTML file name affects JS behavior in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, prototypejs

I'm using [Control.Tabs](http://livepipe.net/control/tabs) (a JavaScript library that uses Prototype) for generating (local) HTML reports. However, if the path contains a space, the tabbing does not work in Chrome (e.g., "C:\test\tab.html" works, but "C:\test 2\tab.html" does not). How does the space affect the JS behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If you are linking to tabs in other pages, I believe it affects the URL handling. Spaces must be replaced by `+`s (See the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)).

Comment: Unfortunately, Chrome cannot find the file if I use the "+" for escaping whitespace (url: "file:///C:/test+2/tab.html")

Comment: Try `%20` instead of `+`. If it still fails, then it might be an issue with the library.